# Is there an efficient genealogy Tree algorithm that allow to capture siblings, parents? (WIth its order)

Tags: algorithm, genealogy

I want to design a genealogy Tree but I don't really know if there is an efficient algorithm to implement is. I used brute force but it is not good. Can you advice an algorithm with its order

Comment: I guess a tree is all you need.

Comment: In practice you will find that it's not a pure tree - but often a directed acyclic graph.